# Pandas Dataframe groupby on 3 columns and make one column lowercase

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, whitespace, case-insensitive

I have a dataframe:

```
   country rating         owner
0  England      a    John Smith
1  England      b    John Smith
2   France      a     Frank Foo
3   France      a     Frank foo
4   France      a  Frank    Foo
5   France      b     Frank Foo
```

I'd like to produce a count of owners after grouping by country and rating and

- ignoring case
- gnoring any spaces ( leading, trailing or inbetween)

I am expecting:

```
   country rating       owner  count
0  England      a  John Smith      1
1  England      b  John Smith      1
2   France      a   Frank Foo      3
3   France      b   Frank Foo      1
```

I have tried:

```
df.group_by(['rating','owner'])['owner'].count()
```

and

```
df.group_by(['rating','owner'].str.lower())['owner'].count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`title`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html) and [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to rework the string and [`groupby.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) to aggregate:

```
out = (df.groupby(['country', 'rating',
                   df['owner'].str.title().str.replace(r'\s+', ' ', regex=True)])
       .size().reset_index(name='count')
      )
```

Output:

```
   country rating       owner  count
0  England      a  John Smith      1
1  England      b  John Smith      1
2   France      a   Frank Foo      3
3   France      b   Frank Foo      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), [`Series.str.title`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html) and remove multiple spaces by [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with aggregate [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

*[`DataFrameGroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html) is used for count exclude missing values, seems not necessary here.*

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['county','rating', 
                   df['owner'].str.strip().str.title().str.replace('\s+',' ', regex=True)])
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Comment: @Max1975 - `strip` remove possible trailing spaces and `replace` remove 2 or more spaces to one inbetween.

Comment: @jezreal Thanks, the strip() deals with the trailing and leading spaces